# Firemonkey form scaling to all mobile device

Tags: delphi, mobile, scale, device

I am developing an Android app using Delphi XE5 but I am having problem scaling my design to fix into all mobile devices within the range of 2.8" and 10.1" mobile devices.

Pointing me to any answered question on this will be appreciated or an example will be most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What I normally do is using the alScale Align property. Here's an example:

[image: Small]
[image: Big]

FMX:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 426
  ClientWidth = 429
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [dkDesktop]
  DesignerMobile = True
  DesignerWidth = 429
  DesignerHeight = 426
  DesignerDeviceName = ''
  DesignerOrientation = 3
  DesignerOSVersion = ''
  object Layout1: TLayout
    Align = alScale
    Height = 426.000000000000000000
    Width = 139.604690551757800000
  end
  object Layout2: TLayout
    Align = alScale
    Height = 426.000000000000000000
    Position.X = 139.236679077148400000
    Width = 155.230239868164100000
  end
  object Layout3: TLayout
    Align = alScale
    Height = 426.000000000000000000
    Position.X = 293.525726318359400000
    Width = 139.236633300781300000
    object Button1: TButton
      Align = alScale
      Height = 26.625030517578130000
      Position.X = 43.169849395751950000
      Position.Y = 358.227325439453100000
      TabOrder = 0
      Text = 'Button1'
      Width = 71.949905395507810000
    end
  end
end
```

PAS:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Layouts;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Layout1: TLayout;
    Layout2: TLayout;
    Layout3: TLayout;
    Button1: TButton;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.
```